# MySQL FULL JOIN on same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want to get something like:

```
fecha       siguiendo    seguidores
2016-01-02    430           1430
2016-01-03    450            NULL
2016-01-04    NULL           5000
```

I have two types of data `seguidores` and `siguiendo`. I want a column for each of them.

I have tried to emulate a FULL JOIN on the same table but I didn't get the expected result. Any ideas?

Comment: table have primary key?

Comment: @a_vlad No. UNIQUE (user_id, dato, fecha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a pivot

```
SELECT fetcha,
SUM(CASE WHEN Dato='siguiendo' THEN valor END) as siguiendo,
SUM(CASE WHEN Dato='seguidores' THEN valor END) as seguidores
FROM t
GROUP BY fetcha
```